# How to use JSfiddle echo feature in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, echo, jsfiddle

Below JS fiddle is the sample echo feature done onload of the page. We are getting the value 1 from the json response.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cevxq/63/)

And, I'm trying to add username and emailid and get back the response. But I'm getting an error like

```
{"error":"key missing: title"}
```

This is my fiddle [OwnJSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydqsa6hv/9/)

Can someone help on this to fix this issue? I wanted to add name and emailid through echo/json and get the response and show in html.

Comment: downvoters pls comment

Comment: error is from the response. i tried adding the title and still the same issue

Comment: Ok which means the error comes from server sided logic. Therefore the JSFiddle does not help. In order to help, we need to know the server code which handles the request.

Comment: @Atterson & all It looks like OP wants to know, how to use the built-in jsFiddle "echo" feature, i.e. the question is about the commonly used tool (jsFiddle), rather than their own code.

Comment: yes, echo/json is the jsfiddle request .. http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: @Teemu: I have tried the same logic what they have in onload with form submit, but cannot able to get it.

Comment: @UI_Dev I'm sorry, I've not time to look at  this just now, but with a quick taken look at the code, add the event listeners with jQuery, no onliners, and then remove the form/prevent it to be submitted.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do exactly. Can you explain? The JSFiddle doesn't work

Comment: If you see the first fiddle, they are getting the json response and showing in the html as value 1 (ajax-json). In my fiddle, I just want to do the same in button click. that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution yet I had to modify your code to work a little differently.

> jQuery Version

[***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/6sqah8p3/46/)

In this fiddle, I add a `submit` event listener to your form.

I use [`e.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent default submit action.

Later, I use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on your JSON object.

---

> Vanilla JS Version

[***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/6sqah8p3/129/)

In this fiddle, I used [`XHR request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to achieve the same thing.

If using XHR requests for `/echo/json/` you need to use the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header and stringify the parameters into the URL even though it's a `POST` request.

---

I'd say the issue was that you were trying to POST via `$.ajax()` and `submit` at the same time.

Comment: Appreciate your work Alex, but it would be great if you can post the same with javascript not with jquery (as I have asked in question)

Comment: I will port it to JS so.

Comment: @UI_Dev, added Vanilla JS version.

Comment: No problem, and I upvoted your question at the very beginning :)